# probability of an entire sequence, not just one value

Tags: ngs, hidden-markov-models

I am reading "`Statistical methods in bioinformatics`"

I came across this formula:
[image]

As explained in the book **O** are the observations:
[image]

My question is why the author only specified $prob(O)$ for a sequence of length=1 ?, I assume he is only talking about one observation, but generally we have a sequence $O_1 ,O_2,O_3,...$.

I assume that $Prob(sequence)= P(O_1).P(O_2)...$ but I am not sure.

Comment: The capital non-indexed O seems to refer to the whole observed sequence (O = O1, O2, ...), so the probability P(O) is of observing the whole sequence of unspecified length. Or, am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The author writes in the quote that $O$ is to be taken for the whole set of positions $O_{i}$.

In the extracts that you provide there is no reason to believe that it is only for a sequence of length 1. The author writes "the observed sequence $O = O_1, O_2...$"

Thus as you say $Pr(sequence) = Pr(O) = Pr(O_1) * Pr(O_2)...$ according to my understanding of the quotes.